# How do I include my own wsdl in my web service in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, asmx

I have a .wsdl file that my web service (old asmx style) must implement. That is taken care of. When I publish the web service you can call it with ?wsdl parameter to get a generated wsdl.

How do I include my .wsdl file so that is the one that is returned instead of the generated one?

Is it possible to do with an attribute in my web service class?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Aren't the two equivalent, if not identical?

Comment: The wsdl is hand made by the caller and the service I have built doesn't look exactly the same. I wan't to do this to be sure that I am fulfilling the callers request.
Now they are getting an error "Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction". When debugging this error I would like to remove every possible fault on my side.

Comment: Here is an old post from pluralsight that I will try out "Using a Custom WSDL File in ASP.NET Web Services": http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/craig/archive/2005/12/15/17482.aspx

Comment: Note that doesn't really work. .NET still emits a WSDL, it just happens to point to your WSDL in a `wsdl:import` element.

Comment: I finally got the web service implementation to work with the supplied wsdl. So I am no longer in need of the answer of this question, even though I do think you should work a a contract-first basis and therefore I would like to supply the contract that I have design and not let the .asmx generate a defualt wsdl (that could look a bit different even if the interface of it is the same).

Answer (score 2):

Is it a given to stay with "old-style" ASMX? Or could you move up to WCF? That's really the most current webservice offering by Microsoft, and if you're doing something new and you're on .NET 3.0 or higher - why spend time on "old" technology?

In WCF, you could definitely define a static physical WSDL file to be used by clients connecting to your metadata endpoint (your "...?wsdl" URL). Not sure if you can do it in ASMX, too.

OK, on ASMX / .NET 2.0, you could of course always put the actual WSDL file under the root of your web site, and then just reference it like this:

```
http://yourwebserver/YourVirtDir/MyService.wsdl
```

I don't know if there's a way to "redirect" the

```
http://yourwebserver/YourVirtDir/MyService.asmx?wsdl
```

call to go to that fixed URL instead. I'm sure someone else will know, though!

Marc

Comment: For now I am stuck on .NET 2.0 and can't use WCF. But I do think that it is possible to work with "contract first" even with asmx and point your ?wsdl request to a separate file.

Comment: It's not possible to point "?wsdl" to a separate file. Just serve the .wsdl file at a separate URL like marc_s suggested.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the confusion of having two different WSDLs available on two different URLs (i.e., the *.asmx?wsdl URL and a custom URL) in your web service application, you could write an HttpModule that intercepts the request to the *.asmx?wsdl URL and returns your custom WSDL instead.

**EDIT:** Here's an example, adapted and simplified from some code I previously wrote that makes a custom WSDL available at the standard *.asmx?wsdl URL.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services.Configuration;

namespace DemoWebService
{
 public class CustomWsdlModule :
  IHttpModule
 {
  public void
  Init(HttpApplication application)
  {
   // hook up to BeginRequest event on application object
   application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.onApplicationBeginRequest);
  }

  public void
  Dispose()
  {
  }

  private void
  onApplicationBeginRequest(object source, EventArgs ea)
  {
   HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
   HttpRequest request = application.Request;
   HttpResponse response = application.Response;

   // check if request is for WSDL file
   if ( request.Url.PathAndQuery.EndsWith(".asmx?wsdl", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) )
   {
    // if Documentation protocol is not allowed, throw exception
    if ( (WebServicesSection.Current.EnabledProtocols & WebServiceProtocols.Documentation) == 0 )
    {
     throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Request format is unrecognized.");
    }

    // get path to physical .asmx file
    String asmxPath = request.MapPath(request.Url.AbsolutePath);

    // build path to .wsdl file; should be same as .asmx file, but with .wsdl extension
    String wsdlPath = Path.ChangeExtension(asmxPath, ".wsdl");

    // check if WSDL file exists
    if ( File.Exists(wsdlPath) )
    {
     // read WSDL file
     using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(wsdlPath) )
     {
      string wsdlFileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();

      // write WSDL to response and end response without normal processing
      response.ContentType = "text/xml";
      response.Write(wsdlFileContents);
      response.End();
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This simplified code assumes that your custom WSDL is in the same folder as your .asmx file with a .wsdl extension. The HttpModule needs to be hooked into your web service application via the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <system.web>
  <!-- ... -->
  <httpModules>
   <add
    type="DemoWebService.CustomWsdlModule"
    name="CustomWsdlModule"/>
   <!-- ... -->
  </httpModules>
  <!-- ... -->
    </system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: -1: The simpler way to avoid the confusion is simply to remove the `Documentation` protocol from the `protocols` element in web.config.

Comment: I suppose this was better suited to be a comment on marc_s' answer than an answer on its own.

However, there is still value in the documentation protocol and having your WSDL at the one URL that developers are familiar with seeing as the WSDL URL for a .asmx web service. This is why I would make sure that if I wanted my custom WSDL available online, I would use an HttpModule or other URL rewriting technology to put my custom WSDL at the expected location.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that would work. I'd suggest you not make such assumptions.

Comment: I only make the assumption because I have previously done it in production code. I have adapted and simplified my code into an example and added it into my above answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate a WSDL and DISCO file by pointing the *disco.exe* tool that ships with the .NET Framework at your web service.

```
 disco.exe http://webserver/MyWebService.asmx
```

The following files are created:

```
 results.discomap
 MyWebService.disco
 MyWebService.wsdl
```

Comment: I don't need to generate a wsdl. The caller has defined the wsdl. I have done an implemetation of an ASP.NET Web Service (.asmx) and now I would like to redirect the references to ?wsdl to this supplied .wsdl file that I got.