# multiple output parameters in .NET web service (without complex type)

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, return-type

Is it possible to create an C# web service which returns multiple strings, without generating a complex type?  (Because my client can't handle complex types and I need to return exactly 2 strings with the names: "wwretval" and "wwrettext")

I've already tried to create a struct or a class or do it with out params, but it always generated a complex type in the WSDL.

Comment: ASMX web service or WCF? Also, does your client _read_ the WSDL? What kind of client is it? Flex? PHP?

Comment: Does the client read the WSDL on every request?

Comment: Yes, it reads it! It's some kind of a java-client. ;)

Comment: *edit, just read your comments on the other items* What happens if you return a string array?

Comment: Most Java clients do _not_ read the WSDL on every request. That's the sort of thing that PHP or other scripting clients do.

Answer (score 1):

Could you send them as an XML blob or, failing that, pack the strings into a single string separater by a nonprinting character such as \n then split them at the other end?

The latter is not exactly elegant but could work.

Since you can't change the client perhaps you can fool it by forcing Soap to use RPC mode with literal binding:

```
namespace WebTest
{
    public struct UploadResponse
    {
        public string wwretval;
        public string wwrettext;
    }

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [SoapRpcMethod(ResponseElementName = "UploadResponse",Use=SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
        [WebMethod]
        public UploadResponse Upload()
        {
           UploadResponse ww = new UploadResponse();

            ww.wwretval = "Hello";
            ww.wwrettext = "World";
            return ww;
        }
    }
}
```

That will generate a response with two strings inside of an UploadResponse element. You can then generate a fake wsdl as described here: [How do I include my own wsdl in my Webservice in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362666/how-do-i-include-my-own-wsdl-in-my-webservice-in-c)

Comment: Since you can't change the client I have added a code snippet to my answer that will generate a response in the right format along with a link to an answer taht shows you how to fake the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the 2 string separated by a ';' . And the client split the string.

(Cowboy coder from hell)

Comment: hum ... but how do you want to send more informations if you don't change it ... can you post the client's code ?

Comment: i didn't write the client. therefore i only know how the wsdl should look like:  <wsdl:message name="UploadResponse">
<wsdl:part name="wwretval" type="xsd:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="wwrettext" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>